# Minecraft Bukkit plugin - PotionEffect by walking over a Block?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to give a player a certain potion effect when he walks over a specified block. Unforunately I couldn't figure it out.

**What I already tried:**

-I searched on youtube for tutorials but haven't found any

Comment: @Apply55gx whilst I appreciate you have put the effort into clearing up the question, your time would be worth more editing questions that aren't considered off-topic for SO. This for one is _too broad_ amongst other reasons. Please don't take this as criticism, it's not. It's just some friendly advice.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this is the absolute best way, but this is how I would do it. I would create a playerMoveEvent (called every time the player moves). Then check to see what the block is under that player by way of getting the location of the player then setting a block object equal to the getblock method in the location class. After that it is a matter of testing to see if it is the block that you want and then applying the potion effect!

Example (Take with grain of salt, I do not have an environment to test this right now):

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvenet event) {
    Player p = event.getPlayer();
    //This might not be the way to get the players location. Bukkit vs Spigot thing
    Location l = p.getLocation();
    l.add(0, -1, 0);
    Block b = l.getBlock();
    if(b.getType() == Material.WHATEVERBLOCKITIS){
        p.addPotionEffect(WHATEVERPOTIONEFFECT);
    }
}
```

If you need help with adding an event to your plugin you can read more about it [here](http://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Event_API_Reference).

Comment: This is probably the only way. I don't think Bukkit has an event for player-walking-on-blocks (e.g. the sort of thing Redstone Ore does when you jump on it) that's generalized for *all* blocks.